# Correct way to use constructor with inner exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Suppose I have a typical application with user-defined exception which throw when file can't be processing. Exception contains user-friendly error message.

```csharp
[Serializable]
public class ProcessingFileException : Exception
{
    public ProcessingFileException() { }
    public ProcessingFileException(string message) : base(message) { }
    public ProcessingFileException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
    protected ProcessingFileException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }
    override public string Message => "Error occurred while file processing...";
}

public class Program
{
    private void DoSomeWithFile() {
        // some action
    }

    public void Main(string[] args) {
        try
        {
            DoSomeWithFile();
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ProcessingFileException("Error occurred while file processing...", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want throw my user-defined exception and pass original exception as inner. But mandatory constructor requires me to pass message and inner exception together [How to create user-defined exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-create-user-defined-exceptions).

```csharp
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new ProcessingFileException("Error occurred while file processing...", ex);
}
```

I don't want duplicate the text of message in my code. Message already defined in my exception.

How to create user-defined exception with original message and caught inner exception. What is best design or approach to solve this?

Comment: Use `ex.Message`?

Comment: Just define the constructors you want to define. None of them are "mandatory". A common way to specifying/augmenting the exception message to pass it to the base ctor rather than overriding `Message`, e.g. `base($"Error occurred while ...: {inner.Message}", inner)`

Comment: Why are you overriding `Message`? You should just be setting it to the value you want via the constructor.

Comment: You can add your own constructor that initialises the message: `public EmployeeListNotFoundException(Exception inner): base("My message", inner){}`

Answer (score 3):

> But mandatory constructor requires me to pass message and inner exception together

There's no *mandatory* constructor. You can define whichever constructor(s) that make sense for that particular Exception type. It's also very common to add custom parameters (such as `ResponseStatusCode` for HTTP-related Exceptions).

This is as simple as:

```
public class ProcessingFileException : Exception
{
    private const string _message = "Error occurred while processing file...";

    public ProcessingFileException() : base(_message)
    {
    }

    public ProcessingFileException(Exception inner) : base(_message, inner) 
    {
    }
}
```

The rest of the constructors aren't normally needed, and `[Serializable]` is just as unlikely to be useful.

Comment: `Serializable` is useful in .NET Framework, because exceptions might be thrown across AppDomains. NET Core / .NET 5+ don't have AppDomains, so `Serializable` is useless

Comment: @canton7 Exception serialization can still be useful - for example, when an `HttpWebRequest` throws an exception and the exception needed to be serialised back to the client (and vice-versa)

Comment: Thank you.  Instead of "private const string _message =>" should be "private const string _message =".

Comment: The first overload as your code stands now does not seem to be legal. `Message` has no (visible) `set` accessor. You should do `: base(_message)` similar to what you have in the other overload. Alternatively, do `: this(_message, null)`.

Comment: Thanks @JeppeStigNielsen, fixed - it's the problem of writing code without an IDE :) I